# What does selector expected mean in this case?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio

I really don’t know how to fix this. I don’t even understand the problem.

@-webkit-keyframes bounce {

Yk It’s underlined in red, but there are no quick fixes available. There just stands „selector expected css(css-selectorexpected)“

I work w visual studio and the part of the code is:

```
span.fr-img-caption.fr-view.fr-dii.fr-fir {
 float: right;
 margin: 5px 0 5px 5px;
 max-width: calc(100% - 5px); }
carsetset,

@-webkit-keyframes bounce {

 from,
 20%,
 53%,
 80%,
 to {
   -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
   animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
   transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 }
```

Comment: `carsetset,` is not  a selector

Comment: `@-webkit-keyframes bounce` creates an animation with the name: bounce. You can use this animation in another part of your css.